# Kubernetes Service not accessible on AWS-EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I created a simple **EKS** cluster on aws as described in https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/tree/master/examples/eks-getting-started.

I this cluster I created an **nginx deployment** and a **service** of type **Loadbalancer** as described below.
The configuration works locally on minikube.

On AWS I can see that pod and service are started, the service has an external ip, I can access the pod with kubectl port-forward and I can ping the LoadBalancer.

However I cannot access the Loadbalancer via the browser via http://a53439687c6d511e8837b02b7cab13e7-935938560.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:3001
I'm getting a `This site can’t be reached`

Any idea where I should look into?

NGinx Deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

NGinx Service

```
{
   "kind":"Service",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"nginx",
      "labels":{
         "app":"nginx"
      }
   },
   "spec":{
      "ports": [
         {
           "port":3001,
           "targetPort":80
         }
      ],
      "selector":{
         "run":"nginx"
      },
      "type": "LoadBalancer"
   }
}
```

Checks

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                              PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      172.20.0.1      <none>                                                                   443/TCP          1h
nginx        LoadBalancer   172.20.48.112   a53439687c6d511e8837b02b7cab13e7-935938560.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com   3001:31468/TCP   45m

kubectl get pod
NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-768979984b-vqz94   1/1       Running   0          49m

kubectl port-forward pod/nginx-768979984b-vqz94 8080:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80

ping a53439687c6d511e8837b02b7cab13e7-935938560.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
PING a53439687c6d511e8837b02b7cab13e7-935938560.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com (62.138.238.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45 (62.138.238.45): icmp_seq=1 ttl=250 time=7.21 ms
```

Service description

```
Name:                     nginx
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"nginx"},"name":"nginx","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port...
Selector:                 run=nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       172.20.48.112
LoadBalancer Ingress:     a53439687c6d511e8837b02b7cab13e7-935938560.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     <unset>  3001/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31468/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.0.181:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  57m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   57m   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

Comment: Not sure if it was a timing issue. It worker after some time without any changes.

Comment: It always takes some minutes before the LoadBalancer is reachable.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I thought it was a timing issue as @nicor88 said, but after waiting for hours the Load Balancer was still unavailable. I also tried creating everything manually but the result was the same.

Comment: I recently add the same issue. It was due to a mismatch between the labels.

Comment: It Takes some time to be available

Comment: @nicor88 is right (I had the same issue): If your service label doesn't match your deployment label, the load balancer won't know where to route the request. To fix this, if your deployment's `template.metadata.labels.app` is "my-app", make sure your service's `spec.selector.app` is "my-app" as well.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the 3 steps below:

1. Check again that the selectors and labels were set correctly between the Service and the Deployment.
2. Inside AWS, Go to "**Instances**" tab of the  Load Balancer (Probably Classic) that was created, and check the **Status** and **Healty** state of all the instances which are related to the LB:

[image]

If the status is not "InService" or State is not "Healthy" - Check the security group of those instances: 
 **The NodePort (31468 in your case) should be open** to accept traffic.

3. View the pod logs with `kubectl logs <pod-name>`.